Dropdown not showing values on mobile
On https://www.faesentertainment.nl/product/ballonnenboog-dubbele-deur/ there is a dropdown and it's not showing the choosen amount on mobile (like IPhone 14). When I try F12 mode in Chrome for acting like a mobile phone it's working as it should be.
But I can't find out what's wrong here in the CSS.
So my main questions are:

What's wrong here in CSS?
How can I fix this kind of issues myself? On Chrome I can use 'Inspect element' and see which CSS is active, but how to do this on by example an iOS device?

